# How would I find the equation of the tangent line or a reciprocal square root function?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, derivatives

I am given the following function:

$y =$ $\frac{2}{\sqrt{x+4}}$

I am asked to find the equation of the tangent line to the above function, specifically at $x=5$. How would I go about doing this? Whenever I do it, I always get an answer of $0$ which can't be right.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Specifically what are you always getting an answer of $0$ to?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

You have to compute the slope $m$  of the tangent line at $(5,y(5))$, i.e. the value of the derivative at $x=5$.

Then use the formula for the equation of a line with known slope $m$ which passes through a given point:
$$y-y(5)=m(x-5).$$